# Replace string field columns with null when field value is empty or len(field.stripe(' \t')) == 0

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

```
%spark.pyspark
l = [('user1', 33, 1.0, 'chess'), ('user2', 34, 2.0, 'tenis'), ('user3', None, None, ''), ('user4', None, 4.0, '   '), ('user5', None, 5.0, 'ski')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(l, ['name', 'age', 'ratio', 'hobby'])
df.show()

root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |-- ratio: double (nullable = true)
 |-- hobby: string (nullable = true)
+-----+----+-----+-----+
| name| age|ratio|hobby|
+-----+----+-----+-----+
|user1|  33|  1.0|chess|
|user2|  34|  2.0|tenis|
|user3|null| null|     |
|user4|null|  4.0|     |
|user5|null|  5.0|  ski|
+-----+----+-----+-----+
```

I'd like to replace string field columns with null when field value is empty or len(field.stripe(' \t')) == 0. In my case, 'hobby' column empty slots should be replaced with null. Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

You can fill empty bu null as

```
df.withColumn("hobby", blank_as_null("hobby"))
```

for checking  `len(field.stripe(' \t')) == 0` 
you can use `UDF`

```
def replace(column, value):
    return when(len(column.stripe(' \t')) == 0, column).otherwise(lit(None))

df.withColumn("y", replace(col("y"), null)).show()
```

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work:

def replace(column, value):
    return when(len(column.stripe(' \t')) == 0, column).otherwise(lit(None))

df.withColumn('hobby', replace(col('hobby'), null)).show()


NameError: name 'null' is not defined


Replacing null with None doesn't work neither.